# Derivative of $x^{\sin x}$

Tags: derivatives

Why $ \sin x.x^{\sin x-1}\cos x$ wrong?
Why I cannot treat $\sin x$ just like usual power
$x^a = ax^{a-1}$

Comment: I see no logs...

Comment: Because there is a big difference between a constant and the sine function?

Comment: Note that $x^{\sin(x)}=e^{\sin(x)\log(x)}$.  Now, use that chain rule and the product rule.

Comment: Let $y=x^{\sin x}$. Take logs, differentiate implicitly and rearrange ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proof of $(x^a)^\prime=ax^{a-1}$ assumes $a$ is constant. [More generally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_differentiation)$$(x^a)^\prime=x^a(a\ln x)^\prime=x^{a-1}(a+xa^\prime\ln x).$$In your case $a=\sin x$, giving the derivative $x^{a-1}(\sin x+x\cos x\ln x)$.

Comment: +1 for answering the actual question of "why is the power rule wrong here?"

Comment: $(x^a)^\prime=x^a(a\ln x)^\prime$ what is it?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter My calculation answered that.

Comment: How $(x^a)^\prime $become $ x^a(a\ln x)^\prime$?

Comment: @Lifeforbetter Let $$y = x^a \implies \ln y = a\ln x \implies \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{y'}{y} = (a\ln x)' \implies y' = y(a\ln x)' = x^a(a\ln x)'$$

Answer (score 3):

Write $$x^{\sin x}=e^{\ln x^{\sin x}}=e^{\sin x \ln x}$$

Taking the derivative we get
$$
e^{\sin x \ln x}(\sin x \ln x)'=e^{\sin x \ln x}\left(\cos x \ln x + \sin x \cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)=x^{\sin x}\left(\cos x \ln x + \sin x \cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)=x^{\sin x -1}(x \cos x \ln x + \sin x)
$$

Answer (score 2):

Writing $$\ln(y)=\sin(x)\ln(x)$$ then we get by the chain rule
$$\frac{y'}{y}=\cos(x)\ln(x)+\sin(x)\times \frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 1):

If you treat $\sin(x)$ as a constant, you get $$\sin(x)x^{\sin(x)-1}$$
If you treat the base as a constant, you get $$x^{\sin(x)}\ln(x)\cos(x)$$
If you add these together, you get $$\sin(x)x^{\sin(x)-1}+x^{\sin(x)}\ln(x)\cos(x)$$
which is the actual derivative of $x^{\sin(x)}$. This is a legitimate application of the multivariate chain rule.

Comment: I also solved this with the same method! but I have some question about that: why this method work? and why it should be "+" between these two derivatives (why add them together why not multiply)? from where this comes?

Comment: Consider $g(u,v)=u\sin(v)$ and $D(x)=(x,x)$. Then $f(x)=(g\circ D)(x)$. And the multivariate chain rule says $\frac{df}{dx}(x)=\left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\right\vert_{(u,v)=D(x)}\cdot\frac{\partial D_1}{\partial x}(x)+\left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right\vert_{(u,v)=D(x)}\cdot\frac{\partial D_2}{\partial x}(x)=\left.\frac{\partial g}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\right\vert_{(u,v)=D(x)}$. It allows you to treat each instance of $x$ as the sole instance of $x$ with everything else constant. But all these contributions towards a rate of change have to be added together.

Answer (score 0):

first consider $x$ as constant then consider $sinx$ as constant:

$[g(x)^{f(x)}]\prime$=[$({x^{f(x)}})^\prime$] +
[$({g(x)}^a)^\prime$]= [$f(x)f(x)^\prime{x^{f(x)-1}}$] +[${g(x)}^a$ $ln(g(x))$ $(g(x))^\prime$]